# Downloading index settings, then applying to index settings in new app

Tags: algolia

I am moving an index to an entirely different app. I have successfully download the index and uploaded it to the new app. I am now trying to move the index settings. I have successfully [downloaded the settings](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js#index-settings), using:

```
index.getSettings(function(err, content) {
    console.log(content);
});
```

However, I am at a loss as to how to apply the settings I've obtained to the index I've uploaded to the new app.

Answer (score 1):

After instantiating the 2 API clients targeting your 2 applications, you can just do:

```
var oldIndex = oldClient.initIndex('indexA');
var newIndex = newClient.initIndex('indexB');
oldIndex.getSettings(function(err, content) {
  newIndex.setSettings(content);
});
```